# How to get injected dependency from scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know is possible get scope from element using:

```
yourScope = angular.element($(".yourTag")).scope();
```

But if I need take dependencies injected in same controller, for example:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

How to can I get `greeter` dependency from `$scope`? This is possible?

Comment: Why are you need to get this dependency from scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the scope or the controller even.

```
// Get the injectable service myService
var x = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('myService');
x.magic();
```

Comment: Unless the controller has to be accessed in a HTML template or something like that. Then you'll need to assign the controller to the `$scope`.

Comment: I think this is what I need! Thank you so so much! and thank you so every body!

Answer (score 5):

Your injected dependencies aren't assigned to any `$scope`.

In your controller, do this:

```
$scope.greeter = greeter;
```

Then, wherever you get the `$scope` variable using `.scope()`, you can use `$scope.greeter` (Assuming you're getting the correct `$scope`).